# nginx rewrite of entire request_uri

Tags: nginx, rewrite

i know there are a ton of examples for this but i just want to make sure. unfortunately i can't test this within the next couple of days so i'm asking here.

what is the rewrite equivalent of this location?

```
location ~* /v1/device/(.*)/ { 
  proxy_pass http://api.domain.com/api/v1.0/download/$1; 
}
```

i want to essentially rewrite the entire incoming request except for the regex'd portion.

i think it's this but i'm not certain:

```
location ~* /v1/device/(.*)/ { 
 rewrite ^/v1/device/(.*)/ /api/v1.0/download/$1 break; 
 proxy_pass http://api.domain.com; 
}
```

**wondering if there is a cleaner way, whereas i don't have to repeat /v1/device/ in the rewrite rule.**

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with the `rewrite` here, since it is simply extra work for nginx...

However, one can simply use the following:

```
location ~* /v1/device/(?<part>.*)/ {
    rewrite ^ /api/v1.0/download/$part break;
    proxy_pass http://api.domain.com;
}
```

We can use the shortest match anything string for the rewrite condition, since the condition is already matched in the `location` block. We also capture the required part into the `$part` variable, which we will then use for the destination.

Another point, your regular expression is a bit loose. It matches for example `/sdhfdsah/v1/device/something/ajkldfkadsfjh/sdfhahfd/file.html`. Also, it matches `/v1/device//something`. I doubt that is the way you intend for it to work, therefore I suggest you use `+` instead of `*` and add starting (^) and ending ($) anchors to the regex.

Comment: and for the rewrite i'm doing ^/v1/device(/.+)$ and just adding $1 at the end of the proxy_pass

Comment: "a good example is worth 3 pages of docs"